# Google Maps API v3 not working in mobile browsers or PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps API v3 not working in mobile browsers or PhoneGap even though i allow all external hosts

I tried while using an apikey or without.

the method `loadMapScript()` is called when the device is ready (on an iDevice(iOS)) or when the page is loaded (on a computer)

when i navigate to the page which has the map, i get the message `"Error Loading map"` which means that `map` is `null`

I suspect that google is detecting that i am using an iOS Device and restricting my usage of their API, but i have no proof of that.

P.S. this works fine on all browsers!
P.S. I tried this in safari for the iPad and it doesn't work! but works on the computer!
P.S. Just checked it doesn't work on any mobile browser or in phonegap, but works in all desktop browsers :/

Any help would be appreciated

The Code:

```
function loadMapScript() {
    if($("#googleMaps").length == 0) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.id = "googleMaps"
        script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initializeMap&key=HIDDEN";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    } else console.log("Error, googleMaps already loaded");
}



function initializeMap(mapOptions) {
    console.log("Init Maps");
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLocation.coords.latitude, currentLocation.coords.longitude);
    if(!mapOptions)
        mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 18,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
    if(!map)
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
    else {
        map.setOptions(mapOptions);
    }
    updateCurrentLocationMarker();
}



function updateCurrentLocationMarker() {
    if(!map) {
        return;
    }
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLocation.coords.latitude,
        currentLocation.coords.longitude);
    if(currentLocationMarker) {
        currentLocationMarker.setMap(null);
    } else {
        currentLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title:"You!"
        });
        currentLocationMarker.setMap(map);
    }
}

function onMapsShow() {
    if(!map) {
        showToastNow("Error Loading map");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could start with the obvious and go from there since I don't see anything glaringly wrong with the code. Since the value of `map` is null, have you tested that the callback to `initializeMap` is actually invoked on your mobile device? Perhaps use the existing script to show a toast indicating you're loading the map.

Comment: I have little bit like issue but my was fixed via changing "https" to "http" in google api url.

Comment: Adding a link to your test site might help you get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this code? I created the code based on your code.
I tried my iPad and that worked.

```
var map, mapOptions, currentLocation, currentLocationMarker;
function loadMapScript() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.id = "googleMaps"
  script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initializeMap";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function initializeMap(mapOptions) {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLocation.coords.latitude, currentLocation.coords.longitude);
  var mapOptions = {
    center : myLatlng,
    zoom : 18,
    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  updateCurrentLocationMarker();
}

function updateCurrentLocationMarker() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLocation.coords.latitude, currentLocation.coords.longitude);

  if (currentLocationMarker) {
    currentLocationMarker.setMap(null);
  } else {
    currentLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position : myLatlng,
      animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      title : "You!",
      map : map
    });
  }
}

function onSuccess(position) {
  currentLocation = position;
  if (!map) {
    loadMapScript();
  }
}

function onError(error) {
  alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

function onDeviceReady() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Comment: Could you explain main things that have been changed?

Comment: Geolocation API of HTML5 allows you to get current location of the browser. So check Geolocation API.

Comment: Update: I recommend using this plugin for phonegap/cordova https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin

Comment: That pugin is not good at all. You can't use most of the useful part of google maps (distance matrix, directions, etc...)